# Making a multicolor bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a line (so basically UIView) that has fixed height and width and is divided to nine segments. I want to be able to control the height of each segment and its color. E.g. I want the first segment be yellow and 30% of the total height of the line, the second to be red and 8% of the total height etc.

I'm not really skilled in Swift, so my solution would be to make 9 UIViews, stack them on top of each other on my storyboard and then manually set the height and background color of every view, so they'd seem like a one multicolored line. Is there cleaner and less bulky solution? Thanks

Comment: Solution sounds fine, though consider proportional constraints

Comment: If you're only doing simple drawing here (just multiple colors stacked on each other), I'd look at overriding `drawRect` and drawing the lines in Core Graphics. Would certainly be a cleaner solution than creating 9 separate subviews.

Comment: @originaluser2 Yeah, just this. Could expand on your solution a little bit?

Comment: To add to what @originaluser2 said, here's a tutorial on Core Graphics http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thanks, will look into that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### I would highly recommend using Core Graphics for this.

As the drawing is dead simple (you just want to stack some colored lines within a view), **you can easily achieve this by subclassing `UIView` and overriding `drawRect()` and drawing them in Core Graphics.**

It's certainly a much cleaner solution than adding 9 subviews!

**Something like this should achieve the desired result:**

```
class LineView : UIView {

    let colors:[UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.greenColor()]
    let values:[CGFloat] = [0.35, 0.45, 0.2]

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let r = self.bounds // the view's bounds
        let numberOfSegments = values.count // number of segments to render

        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() // get the current context

        var cumulativeValue:CGFloat = 0 // store a cumulative value in order to start each line after the last one
        for i in 0..<numberOfSegments {

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, colors[i]) // set fill color to the given color
            CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, cumulativeValue*r.size.height, r.size.width, values[i]*r.size.height)) // fill that given segment

            cumulativeValue += values[i] // increment cumulative value
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Going further...

You could allow the `colors` and `values` properties to be changed from outside the `LineView` class, allowing for much greater flexibility. You just have to override the `didSet` to trigger the view to be redrawn when the properties change.

**For example:**

```
class LineView : UIView {

    /// An array of optional UIColors (clearColor is used when nil is provided) defining the color of each segment.
    var colors : [UIColor?] = [UIColor?]() {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    /// An array of CGFloat values to define how much of the view each segment occupies. Should add up to 1.0.
    var values : [CGFloat] = [CGFloat]() {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let r = self.bounds // the view's bounds
        let numberOfSegments = values.count // number of segments to render

        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() // get the current context

        var cumulativeValue:CGFloat = 0 // store a cumulative value in order to start each line after the last one
        for i in 0..<numberOfSegments {

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, colors[i]?.CGColor ?? UIColor.clearColor().CGColor) // set fill color to the given color if it's provided, else use clearColor
            CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(0, cumulativeValue*r.size.height, r.size.width, values[i]*r.size.height)) // fill that given segment

            cumulativeValue += values[i] // increment cumulative value
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let lineView = LineView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 20, view.bounds.size.height-100))

lineView.colors = [
    UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 31.0/255.0, blue: 73.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), // red
    UIColor(red:1.0, green: 138.0/255.0, blue: 0.0, alpha:1.0), // orange
    UIColor(red: 122.0/255.0, green: 108.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), // purple
    UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 100.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), // dark blue
    UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 241.0/255.0, blue: 183.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), // green
    UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 222.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) // blue
]
lineView.values = [0.15, 0.1, 0.35, 0.15, 0.1, 0.15]

view.addSubview(lineView);
```

[image]

(I've only added 6 colors here, but you can add as many as you want).

---

**Full project: https://github.com/hamishknight/Color-Segment-Line-View**

Comment: @Sh4rPEYE happy to help!

Comment: How can we create like multiple lines for this?

Answer (score 2):

*I've just realized that this was not what you needed.
I leave the answer anyway so that maybe could be helpful to somebody else in the future.*

Make sure your line view has it's own UIView subclass, so that we can override `drawRect` and achieve your goal.

Then a **simple implementation** would be:

```
class BarLine: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        //Height of each segment, in percentage
        var heights  : [CGFloat]    = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]

        //Lets create 9 rects and set each rect width to be 1/9th of the view size, then add them to the array
        let width   : CGFloat   = rect.size.width / 9.0


        var i       : Int       = Int()

        //Loop to generate 9 segmnets
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            //Each rect origin must be translated by i * width
            let origin  = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i) * width, rect.height)

            //Generate a random color
            let color   = UIColor(red: heights[i], green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
            let segment = CGRect(x: origin.x, y: origin.y, width: width, height: -heights[i] * rect.height)

            //Set the color
            color.set()

            //Add the segment to the view by drawing it
            UIRectFill(segment)

        }


    }

}
```

This will produce something like :

[image]

(Remember to set your UIView class to you custom class in IB)

I hope this helped

Comment: Still an admirable answer, even if it wasn't quite what OP wanted ;)

Answer (score 1):

To make @[Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/hamish) code compatible for Swift 5, here the LineView class (and invert width & height in draw->fill to make it horizontal):

```
import UIKit

public class ColorLineView : UIView {

    public var colors : [UIColor?] = [UIColor?]() {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    public var values : [CGFloat] = [CGFloat]() {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let r = self.bounds
        let numberOfSegments = values.count

        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        var cumulativeValue:CGFloat = 0
        for i in 0..<numberOfSegments {

            ctx.setFillColor(colors[i]?.cgColor ?? UIColor.clear.cgColor)
            ctx.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: cumulativeValue*r.size.height, width: r.size.width, height: values[i]*r.size.height))

            cumulativeValue += values[i]
        }
    }
}
```